# Send and retrieve a custom field in Socialize laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

How can I sent a custom field in socialize laravel in `RedirectToProvider` method using this method:

```
if ($social == 'facebook') {
    return Socialize::with($social)->fields([
                'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
            ])->scopes([
                'email', 'user_birthday'
            ])->redirect();
}
```

suppose i want to send network_id => 9.

And then how can I get it in my handler method where I am getting user information?

```
$user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way i found to get the parameters using Socialite is storing it in the Session

```
public function redirectToFacebookProvider()
{
    // save anything you will need later, for example an url to come back to
    Session::put('url.intended', URL::previous());

    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect(); 
}

public function handleFacebookProviderCallback()
{
    // handling....

    $url = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
    Session::forget('url.intended');

    return redirect($url);
}
```

Obtained this answer [from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/socialite-return-parameters-in-callback?page=0](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/socialite-return-parameters-in-callback?page=0)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

And then retrieve items from the $user array, like so

```
$user['email']
```